# centering relative layout on Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the following Relative layout. The view at the bottom is simply a dividing line. 
When I include the dividing line, the whole layout aligns to the left. However when I remove the dividing line it centers which is how I want it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Type"
    android:text="@string/type_button"
    android:onClick="TypeClick"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
>
</Button>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/colour"
    android:text="@string/colour_button"
    android:onClick="ColourClick"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Type"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
    >
</Button>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:text="@string/size_button"
    android:onClick="SizeClick"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colour"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
   >
</Button>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/mode"
    android:text="@string/mode_button"
    android:onClick="HabitatClick"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/size"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
    >
</Button>

       <Button
    android:id="@+id/keyword"
    android:text="@string/keyword_button"
    android:onClick="KeywordClick"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/habitat"    

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
   >
</Button>  


<Button
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:text="@string/search_button"
    android:onClick="SearchClick"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyword"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"

    android:textSize = "15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonType1"
    android:textColor="@color/DarkGrey"

    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"

    android:clickable="false"
   >
</Button>

<View
   android:background="@color/White"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_below="@+id/search"
 ></View>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try the answer below,and if any confusion ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve the problem,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Type" android:text="@string/type_button"
            android:onClick="TypeClick" android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp" android:textSize="15dp"

            android:textColor="#00ff0f" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/colour" android:text="@string/colour_button"
            android:onClick="ColourClick" android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Type"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp">
        </Button>


        <Button android:id="@+id/size" android:text="@string/size_button"
            android:onClick="SizeClick" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/colour"

            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="55dp"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/mode" android:text="@string/mode_button"
            android:onClick="HabitatClick" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/size"

            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="55dp"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/keyword" android:text="@string/keyword_button"
            android:onClick="KeywordClick" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/habitat"

            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="55dp"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp">
        </Button>


        <Button android:id="@+id/search" android:text="@string/search_button"
            android:onClick="SearchClick" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyword"

            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="55dp"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="#00ff0f"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp" android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"

            android:clickable="false">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:background="#00ff0f">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```